# PrimeFaces PieChart not working

Tags: java, eclipse, primefaces, charts, pie-chart

im having trouble getting the basic primefaces pie chart working.
im using primefaces 4.0, eclipse kepler and glassfish 4.0
The error im getting is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.primefaces.model.chart.PieChartModel
```

xhtml:

```
<p:pieChart value="chart.model" legendPosition="w" />
```

Java:

```
package server;

import org.primefaces.model.chart.PieChartModel;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

public class Chart  implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private PieChartModel model;
    public Chart()
    {
        model = new PieChartModel();
        model.set("Brand1", 540);
        model.set("Brand2", 325);
        model.set("Brand3", 702);
        model.set("Brand4", 421);       
    }
    public PieChartModel getModel()
    {
        return model;
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error comes from this:

`<p:pieChart value="chart.model" legendPosition="w" />`

Your value should be: `value="#{chartBean.chart.model}"`

Where chartBean is an annotated ManagedBean.

```
@ManagedBean(name="chartBean")
@YOURSCOPE (might be Request, Session etc...)
public class ChartBean implements Serializable{
  Chart chart;

  //you should initialize your bean in the constructor, or somewhere in the class, like
  public ChartBean(){
    ...
    Chart = new Chart();
    ...
  }

  public Chart getChart(){
    return this.chart;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this really helped I eventually got it working using your answer